# I have 8GB Memory, swapness set to 40%, why the swap space is full and can't run VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, memory-usage, memory-leak

I am using ArchLinux 64-bit, 8GB Memory. My harddisk sometimes go crazy read/write and freezing other apps. I found that I can't run Virtualbox and the Virtualbox pops up an error says **Memory allocation failed. (VERR_NO_MEMORY).**.

```
vmstat -s
      8077432 K total memory
      7671376 K used memory
      6028420 K active memory
      1476900 K inactive memory
       406056 K free memory
        19512 K buffer memory
      6214272 K swap cache
      4097236 K total swap
      4097236 K used swap
            0 K free swap
     14489927 non-nice user cpu ticks
      8395500 nice user cpu ticks
     12570270 system cpu ticks
    269638414 idle cpu ticks
      4909480 IO-wait cpu ticks
           64 IRQ cpu ticks
        24615 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
    108297968 pages paged in
     98410480 pages paged out
       546719 pages swapped in
      1910237 pages swapped out
   1503045631 interrupts
   3753058202 CPU context switches
   1340852017 boot time
       335348 forks

free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7888       7491        396          0         19       6068
-/+ buffers/cache:       1403       6484
Swap:         4001       4001          0
```

The guest VM is Windows 7 with 1024 MB for system memory and 256M for video memory.

Comment: And how much memory have you set for the guest in your virtual machine configuration?

Comment: The guest VM is Windows 7 with 1024 MB for system memory and 256M for video memory.